# Conflito Jquery e MetisMenu e Modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, modal

Estou tendo conflito com Jquery e MetisMenu e Modal(bootstrap):

se eu ref. assim funciona o modal, mas não funciona o menu dropdown:

```
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Agora se eu citar o jquery primeiro o menu funciona, mas o modal abre e some rapidamente:

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido atualizando a versão.
link: https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu

e mantendo o bootstrap antes do jquery:

```
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```